# Copy specific data from Production database to QA

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using SQL as database server and SQL management studio to access.

I need to test an issue that is happening on the PRD system on the QA.

There are around 7-10 tables and each table has one entry associated with the request that I want to copy from PRD to QA with MeetingNo as primary key in each table.

The problem is, QA and PRD databases are on different database servers and I only have read access to the PRD database. Hence I am not able to take backup.

How can this be done?
Please help

Comment: ask the DBA to provide you with a recent backup, if it's a production db they should be pretty frequent. Otherwise you'll have to do some thing with bulk export and bulk import tools, or something (hint: there is a lot more than just SSMS you can use, potentially).

Comment: @ADyson can you suggest please?

Answer (score 0):

Can an do it in 2 ways

**First** -

•   Execute the query on Prod which will give you required result.

•   Copy the data from output window

•   On the Test server  go to- object Explorer--databases-->select your DB --> Tables --> select you table where you want to insert data --> select edit top 200 rows

•   At the end select row header and past your copied data from prod

**Second** – 
Copy your result into excel and upload it into your test DB using import export wizard.

Go to object Explorer-->databases-->right click --> tasks --> import data

Comment: Thanks Rahul, the first method won't work as I can't perform edit. Yes I am doing it by second option itself as of now. But do you know if it can be done by query or any other method?

Comment: if you have permissions you can use " bulk insert " from query window of test server.

Comment: @M.F. "first method won't work as I can't perform edit"...you don't have edit permission to the test server? Then how are you going to insert anything, or meaningfully do any testing? In this context an edit (via the SSMS GUI) amounts to an insert of rows.

Comment: @ADyson, I have read and write access, but right click and edit is disabled. It shows permission denied

Comment: @M.F. then you'll have to write some INSERT statements, or use another bulk import method. You can google all the different possibilities if you search for SQL Server bulk import and export, I can't suggest exactly what is going to be best for your situation, there are many different ways to do it depending on your environment and what is installed etc. Or, ask the DBA to remove this arbitrary restriction - if you can write rows to the DB, there's no reason not to be able to do it via the GUI, really.